# How to fix the Incompatible block pointer types sending error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c-blocks

The Build fails because of the incompatible block pointer types sending error .

```
- (void)loadAndConfigureWithCompletion:(void (^ _Nonnull)(BOOL, NSError * _Nullable))completion;
```

```
[SkyIdConfigure.shared loadAndConfigureWithCompletion:^(BOOL *isConfigured,NSError *error){
    if (error) {
    }
    if (isConfigured) {
    }
}];
```

I have this Error !!

`Incompatible block pointer types sending 'int (^)(BOOL *, NSError * _Nullable)' to parameter of type 'void (^ _Nonnull)(BOOL, NSError * _Nullable)' Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(BOOL *, NSError *)' to parameter of type 'void (^ _Nonnull)(BOOL, NSError * _Nullable)'`

Comment: First parameter - it is not a *pointer* in the definition and you pass a pointer to it when you call it.

Comment: Just write the types one above the other.You'll see that for the boolean parameter, there is a pointer: `*` in your code, but not in the declaration. Ask you: why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take one error message!

A little tip, put the expected and the current above the other one, it will be easier to spot differences. I do it when I can't spot the difference.

```
Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(BOOL *, NSError *)' to parameter of type 'void (^ _Nonnull)(BOOL, NSError * _Nullable)'
```

=>

```
Incompatible block pointer types sending 
'void (^)(BOOL *, NSError *)' 
to parameter of type 
'void (^ _Nonnull)(BOOL, NSError * _Nullable)'
```

=>

```
'void (^)(BOOL *, NSError *)'                  //You wrote
'void (^ _Nonnull)(BOOL, NSError * _Nullable)' //Expected
```

=>

```
'void (^         )(BOOL *, NSError *          )' //You wrote
'void (^ _Nonnull)(BOOL  , NSError * _Nullable)' //Expected
                        ^
                        |____________________________
                                                     |
```

`Nonnull`/`Nullable`, that's one thing, but you notice the extra `*` for the boolean?
You're having a pointer, you have directly the value.

```
[SkyIdConfigure.shared loadAndConfigureWithCompletion:^(BOOL *isConfigured, NSError *error) {
}];
```

=>

```
[SkyIdConfigure.shared loadAndConfigureWithCompletion:^(BOOL isConfigured, NSError *error) {
}];
```